# Java Swing question mark button

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a little question mark help button such as this one:
[image]

Is there an Object for this like JQuestionMarkButton or similar that i can use and place just like a JButton with an action listener? 
Secondly, is it possible that when it is clicked, it displays a message balloon near by? It would be nicer to have this than another window open up with help.

Comment: Maybe a `JButton` with an `Icon` or unicode symbol?  Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: I dont have an example, all the code i could give you is a JPane where i add numerous components (JLabel, JComboBox...). which would be no good. Im looking to see if there exists such a button in Java swing i could use similarly to the other components.

Comment: See [*How to Use Buttons*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for example code.

Comment: I see. I have to make a custom button, there is no JQuestionMarkButton

Comment: Custom? I would avoid extending `JButton`; `setIcon` or `setText` should be enough.

Comment: Note: [JOptionPane has some icons you can use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features)

Comment: If i `setIcon()`, does the button take the shape of the Icon? Ideally the button should be small and circular.